# Why am I getting the "format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *' but...." error here?

Tags: c, reverse

I'm pretty new to C and still catching onto the basics.  I am writing a very simple practice exercise which takes a phrase and reverses it.  I'm sure there are other problems with this code, but primarily on compilation of main.c, I am continually getting the error

*main.c:14:9: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type char* but argument 2 has type 'int'   command not found*

I have no idea why I am getting that error, could someone help me understand why?  Thank you!

My main.c

```
int main (int argc, char * argv [])
{

char word[] = "Happy Birthday!";

printf("%s\n", word);
reverse(word);
printf("%s\n", word);
printf("%s\n", reverse(word));
printf("%s\n", word);

system ("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

My reverse.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *reverse(char *word)
{
char *rev;
char *i;
char temp;

rev = word;
for (i = word; *i != '\0'; i++)
{
        if (i - word > 1)
                for (i--; word < i; word++, i--)
                {
                        temp = *word;
                        *word = *i;
                        *i = temp;
                }

return rev;
}
```

Comment: Do you also have a warning about calling an undeclared function `reverse()`?

Comment: You should also be getting a warning about an implicit declaration of function `reverse()`.  If not, then turn up your compiler's warning level.  In the absence of an in-scope prototype at the point where you call that function, the compiler assumes that its return type is `int`.

Comment: @xing `reverse` is in another unit, is better to `#include "reverse.h"` before `main`

Comment: It is illegal to call a function that had not been declared. If your compiler doesn't warn you about this, it's too old, upgrade it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's your entire `main.c` source file, then the compiler doesn't see a declaration of your `reverse` function.

In C89/C90, a call to an undeclared function would create an implicit declaration of that function returning a result of type `int`. If the function actually returns something other than `int`, as yours does, then the behavior is undefined.

C99 dropped this "implicit `int`" rule, making any call to an undeclared function a *constraint violation*, requiring a diagnostic.  You should find out how to coax your compiler to diagnose such a call.

The fix is to make a declaration of `reverse` visible in `main.c`.  The best way to do this is to create a header file, most likely `reverse.h`, that contains the declaration:

```
#ifndef REVERSE_H
#define REVERSE_H

char *reverse(char *word);

#endif
```

and `#include` that header in both `main.c` and `reverse.c`.  (Including it in `main.c` provides the declaration so the call can be compiled correctly. Including it in `reverse.c` lets the compiler conform that the declaration and definition are consistent.)

Comment: I added the declaration into my main.c file, but am still getting the same error.  I realize its better form to create a header file, so I will do that.  But I am assuming if adding the declaration to the main.c file is still giving me the same warning, creating a header will still give me the warning also?

Comment: So problem 1 fixed, I was declaring as 'char reverse' instead of 'char *reverse'.

I've set it up as you suggested but am still getting the lingering undefined reference to reverse

Comment: @Mike: "undefined reference" sounds like a link-time error. How to fix that depends on what compiler you're using, but if you're using gcc, the simplest approach is `gcc reverse.c main.c -o main`. Or `gcc -c reverse.c ; gcc -c main.c ; gcc reverse.o main.o -o main`. Or any of a myriad of variations, including setting up a `Makefile` or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't include the declaration of your `reverse()` function in the `main.c` file (module), the compiler (with suppressed appropriate warning flag) suppose it returns `int`.

So include the statement

```
char *reverse(char *word);
```

at the start of your `main.c` file.

Comment: Thanks, however I added just that at the start of my main.c file and I am getting exactly the same error as before :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was​ the type of the reverse function. Here is an alternative code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void reverse(char *word)
{
    size_t i;
    size_t length = strlen(word);
    size_t tmp;
    for (i = 0; i < (length / 2); i++) {
        tmp = length-i-1;
        /* This is a xor swap. */
        word[i] ^= word[tmp];
        word[tmp] ^= word[i];
        word[i] ^= word[tmp];
    }
}

int main (int argc, char * argv [])
{
    char word[] = "Happy Birthday!";
    printf("%s\n", word);
    reverse(word);
    printf("%s\n", word);
    reverse(word);
    printf("%s\n", word);
    printf("%s\n", word);
    system ("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the proof:
[Run code](https://ideone.com/xp4lDj)